# Get the last value of a variable in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I have this function:

```
function sum(x, y) {
    var z = 1;
    for (var i = x; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i % y == (x % y)) {
            console.log(z *= i);
        }
    }
}

sum(12, 5);
```

and the output is:

```
12, 84, 168
```

What should I edit in my function in order to get only the last value (168)?

Answer (score 1):

Move the log outside:

```
function sum(x, y) {
var z = 1;
for (var i = x; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i % y == (x % y)) {
        z *= i;
    }
}
console.log(z);
}

sum(12, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(x, y) {
var z = 1;
for (var i = x; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i % y == (x % y)) {
        z *= i;
    }
}
console.log(z);
}
sum(12, 5);
```